# Get value from spinner and put it into an array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

I am trying to make a drop-down menu with Spinner where users can choose a number. Then the number that user has clicked will be put in an array, and the program will count the total numbers inside the array. But it cannot add the selected item into an array. I have been looking through many articles; however, I cannot find a solution.

Here is my code:

**Update**: I was able to figure out the solution to get the selected items into an array list, but I could not get the result of the total items in the array.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        //Declare an array to store units
        public static ArrayList<Double> unitsAdd = new ArrayList<Double>();
        //Declare spinner
        Spinner spinner;
        //Declare adapter to connect array in string value
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
        //
        Double num1, totalUnits;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

            adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this, R.array.units,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            //display the adapter contain the list
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            //delcare buttons
            Button bntInsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntInsert);
            Button bntCount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntCount);
            //Declare textView
            final TextView resultTotalUnits = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTotalUnits);
            //Insert function
            bntInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    /*Removed This line of codes
               spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
               AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position, long id) {
                            //define selected unit. I am missing something right here
                            String unitSelected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            //convert string to double
                            num1 = Double.parseDouble(unitSelected);
                            //add to array but it does not work
                            unitsAdd.add(num1);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "You have inserted: " + num1 + " units",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                        }
                    });*/
//Added these
String unitSelected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(unitSelected);
                unitsAdd.add(num1);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "You have inserted: " + unitsAdd + " units",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    //When clicking the button, the app stopped working
           bntCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   for(int i=0;i<unitsAdd.size();i++){
                       //sum of the array called units
                       totalUnits =  (unitsAdd.get(i)) + totalUnits;
                   }
                   //Display the results in the TextView sections
                   resultTotalUnits.setText("Total units :"+Double.toString(totalUnits));
               }
           });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you having issues with it?

Comment: It cannot add the selected item (the item that user choose when click insert button) into an array.

Comment: Try that `String unitSelected = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()`

Comment: Sorry, I have tried that. Tt was not working. Thank you.

Comment: Alright, I would suggest going through it one line one then. First, make sure unitSelected gets the correct string value, then if it gets parsed correctly, etc...

Comment: Thanks @KiarashTorkian

Comment: Is the `Toast` showing the correct value after each selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in this line

```
String unitSelected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

The spinner does not hold the selected value, the `AdapterView` that is one of the parameters of the `onSelected()` function holds the selected value.

Change that statement to

```
String unitSelected = list.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Edit:

I think the implementation is somewhat wrong. Try this:

1. Declare a static double variable that will hold the value selected by the spinner.
2. Then implement a normal Adapter for the Spinner. Each time the Spinner is selected get that value in the adapter and store it in the static varaible.
3. When the button is clicked get the value from the static variable and add it to the `ArrayList`

Sample Code:

```
Static Double selectedDouble;

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(myListener);
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener myListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                selectedDouble = Double.parseDouble(item);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            adapterView.setSelection(0);
            selectedDouble = Double.parseDouble("Some Default Value");

        }
    };

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             DoubleArray.add(selectedDouble);
        }

        });
```

Initialse the varaible totalUnits to 0 before performing any operations on it. preferably in `onCreate()`.

`totalUnits = 0.00;`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this already; however, it did not add anything to the array, it just selected the item; plus it selected the item without clicking the insert button (bntInsert).

Comment: @TanDo Is your `Toast ` showing the value you selected correctly? The `onItemSelected()` will be executed automatically when the spinner is loaded.

Comment: I figured out the solution to add the items to an array already. By removing these line of code spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    ...};

Comment: This line of code is a solution                                                              String unitSelected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(unitSelected);
                unitsAdd.add(num1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You have inserted: " + unitsAdd + " units",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                   
 But the count total units in an array is not working (the last function).

Comment: Wow you are amazing. Problem solved. Thank you a lot. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you were more clear in your question. I would have solved this sooner. Happy to help. @TanDo

Answer (score 0):

Remove this call that is not required:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Instead, pass `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` here as,

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this, R.array.units,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```